# Going back to initial storyboard ViewController on logout

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboards in my iOS. The first screen is the login screen. When a user logs out or gets logged out, he may be on a screen in a deep hierarchy.

For example: login view controller => modal view controller => tab bar controller => nav controller => view controller => view controller. I want to go all the way back from the top-most view controller to the bottom one.

Edit: Here's a diagram of the view hierarchy:[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a category for UIViewControllers that seems to be working:

```
- (void) popToInitialViewController
{
    UIViewController *vc;
    if (self.navigationController != nil) {
        vc = self.navigationController;
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        [vc popToInitialViewController];
    }
    else if (self.tabBarController != nil) {
        vc = self.tabBarController;
        [vc popToInitialViewController];
    }
    else if (self.presentingViewController != nil) {
        vc = self;

        while (vc.presentingViewController != nil)
            vc = vc.presentingViewController;

        [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        [vc popToInitialViewController];
    }
}
```

Comments are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

this should work assuming everything was pushed onto the navigation stack:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: ah i see, nice diagram. You might have to also use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification on logout. Your first modal view controller could listen for the notification and dismiss itself when it receives it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I directly set the **rootViewController** of the **window** like so:

```
func popToInitialScreen() {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    window.rootViewController = nil
    window.rootViewController = // init your initial view controller
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

P.S keyWindow is deprecated in iOS 13 and should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes.